# Disable scroll with mousewheel click (auxclick event)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

I'm using angular 9 and I have the event of `(auxClick)` where is triggered with the `mousewheel click`. The problem is that when in the page there is a scroll, and you click the `mousewheel`, it doesn't trigger the event and opens the autoscroll with the mouse.

This is the thing I want to disable
[image]

I wanted to know if there is anyway to disable this wiht JS / TS in angular.

Thank you in advance.

(The `preventDefault()` does not work, since the event is not triggered, doesn't enter the callback function)

Comment: Did you find answer already?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the scrolling effect on your element using jQuery or just Vanilla JS like this:

## jQuery:

```
$('YourElement').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 2) {
    preventDefault();
    // OR return false;
  }
});
```

## Vanilla JS:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("YourClassHere")[0].onmousedown = function(e) {
  if (e.which === 2) {
    preventDefault();
    // OR return false;
  }
};
```

and of course you can use `getElementById` to use `id` or `getElementsByTagName` to use its `tag` etc, though you might need to change the index if necessary or remove it if using `id`.